# margin-top to straight bottom of two elements

Tags: html, css

In the following simple CSS code, I’m trying to straight the bottom of `h1` with the bottom of `p` (`h1` shouldn’t be under `p` like in my code).

```
<div id="sqrs" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid BLACK;">
<p style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:BLUE; float:right;">blue</p>
<h1 style="background-color:YELLOW; margin-top:100px;">yellow</h1>
</div>
```

`P` style cannot be changed and I don’t know the `height` of `h1` (since it can be `h2`, `h3`…)

I’ve tried `margin-top:100%` (instead `margin-top:100px`) but this is not the solution as well.

Thanks,

Comment: jsfiddle or url please..

Comment: thanks for replying but I cannot find the answer.

Comment: i didnt answer yet !! do you have any live url for your page so that i can check

Comment: add your working code here then only people can check http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Since its not clear I'm going to run through what I think your requirements are: You want a black frame 200x200. You want the top right quarter (100x100) to be a blue box with the word blue written in it. You want a heading whose bottom of text should be aligned with the bottom of the blue box but should be on the left. Is that about right?

Comment: @SACHIN: He has put code into his question. What more are you after (apart from putting it in a fiddle which anybody can do: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/3sWEt/)?

Comment: i am not getting what exact he want ..so want to take exact requirment rather then give answer by asum what he want just like you

Comment: yes, it's correct. like mentioned in the subject of my posting, how can I use margin-top to straight the bottom of h1 with the bottom of p (really quite simple, but I cannot do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/3sWEt/3/

You can set `position:relative` to a container and `position:absolute` with `bottom:0` to the `<h1>`:

CSS:

```
#sqrs{
    width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#sqrs>*{
    height:100px;
}
#sqrs>p{
    width:100px; background-color:blue; float:right;
}
#sqrs>div{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#sqrs>div>h1{
    background-color:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sqrs">
    <p>blue</p>
    <div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/3sWEt/1/

```
#sqrs{
    width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid black;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:right;
}
#sqrs>*{
    text-align:left;
    line-height:normal;
}
#sqrs>p{
    width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; float:right;
}
#sqrs>h1{
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

You can use same `line-height`, `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:bottom`.

But the problem is that the `<h1>` doesn't expand it's width to cover it's parent's remaining width.